# Lumia 830 - 5.1 Dolby Video plays only stereo in PC

Tags: lumia, video, audio, nokia-lumia-830

I own a Lumia 830. When I record videos with 5.1 surround sound, the video on PC plays only in stereo. But in VLC I see another audio channel - `audio 2` with the same track. Nevertheless, the `audio device` still shows it as `stereo`. How do I get to play the video in 5.1?

Comment: I'm trying to find confirmation, but I don't think the phone is able to record in true 5.1 surround sound - it uses a technique to emulate it. When playing back the video, try listening on headphones both on the phone and PC (try both audio tracks)?

Comment: Are you sure? I have heard people say that it does record in 5.1 :/